# PictureListener is deprecated and obsolete, is there a replacement?

Tags: android, webview, deprecated

I would like to be notified when an image has been completely draw on the WebView.  Using [PictureListener and onNewPicture](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.PictureListener.html) is a common answer (even suggested by the [onPageFinished documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html)) to this but is listed as deprecated and obsolete.  Is there a replacement/alternative?

Comment: Isn't that what onLoadResource() is for? Maybe I'm wrong. How about overloading this, calling super.onLoadResource() and then checking for the file type?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I see with Android 4.0 the doc was updated:

> This method is deprecated. Due to internal changes, the picture does
>   not include composited layers such as fixed position elements or
>   scrollable divs. While the PictureListener API can still be used to
>   detect changes in the WebView content, you are advised against its
>   usage until a replacement is provided in a future Android release.

There is no replacement yet.

Answer (score -1):

how about

```
webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        // you can get the picture here
        super.onPageFinished(view, url);

    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks Tamas but onPageFinished notifies you when the main frame is finished loading but the rendering picture may not be updated yet. The [onPageFinished documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html) suggests onNewPicture which puts me back to the question again.

Comment: onPageFinished() sometimes called before the web UI is rendered.