# WebView does not display loaded Html on some phones

Tags: android, android-webview

I have a `WebView` in one of my `Activities` where I want to load a `Html` page. The page contains `jquery-mobile` and some `html`. So I do the following in my `Activity` :

```
    mWebView=(WebView) findViewById(R.id.MyWebView);
    mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
           [...]
    });
    mWebView.loadUrl("http://www.mymobilepage.html");
```

The problem is that the page gets loaded and displayed on the emulator, and on a HTC Desire, but when I try to load it on a LG Optimus One nothing gets displayed. The events `onPageStarted` and `onPageFinished` both get fired in my `WebViewClient` but just a blank page is displayed, and also I don't have any errors in my `LogCat`.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Make a simple html page with no jquery and try then? Is the LG Optimus One still giving you a blank page. It looks like a some kind of jquery problem...

Comment: can you give full code for this issue?????

Comment: full code for what? Of the webpage? I can not :)

Comment: @SYLARRR yes, if I place another webpage int the WebView it gets displayed

Comment: I had the same problem with Optimus GT540 on Android 2.1. Some pages just "refused" to load randomly. I had the same issue when just browsing web in default browser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When onPageFinished is called, the page may not be completely rendered. The [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html) states:

> Notify the host application that a page has finished loading. This method is called only for main frame. When onPageFinished() is called, the rendering picture may not be updated yet. To get the notification for the new Picture, use onNewPicture(WebView, Picture).

However, note that [onNewPicture](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.PictureListener.html) is documented as deprecated and obsolete.  I ask about a replacement/alternative [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7166534/picturelistener-is-deprecated-and-obsolete-is-there-a-replacement).

Answer (score 0):

This should be a comment, but since there is a bit of code on it I've added as response.

Try changing default background to transparent and alerting as soon as the page is loaded, just to be sure that at least the html is being interpreted:

```
    mWebView = (WebView) this.findViewById(R.id.webview);
    mWebView.setBackgroundColor(0);
    mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(false);
    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url)
        {
         super.onPageFinished(view, url);
         view.loadUrl("javascript:(function() { alert('hello'); })()");
        } });
```

and when loading the webpage:

```
    mWebView.clearView();
    mWebView.loadUrl("http://yourmobilepage.something/");
```

and let us know if something happened.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
webView.post(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // Your code here...

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked your html/js code with different versions on the emulator? Newer Android versions have newer versions of WebKit, that might be the problem.

I would also check if you have LogCat set to show Error messages only, or Debug+Info+Warning+Error messages. According to [this](http://www.nanaze.com/2009/01/debugging-javascript-on-android.html), the javascript errors should show up as Debug messages.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue to this, I found that calling clearview and then reload seemed to clear it up -- as in:

```
mWebView.clearView();
mWebView.loadUrl("http://yourmobilepage.something/");
mWebView.reload();
```