# PictureListener and onNewPicture() are deprecated - Alternatives?

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

The [Android Developers reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.PictureListener.html#onNewPicture%28android.webkit.WebView,%20android.graphics.Picture%29) says that both the `WebView.PictureListener` interface and its `onNewPicture()` method are deprecated.

Fine, but the need to know when WebView renders a picture is still there. Is there an alternative way to accomplishing this?

Comment: Isn't that what onLoadResource() is for? Maybe I'm wrong. How about overloading this, calling super.onLoadResource() and then checking for the file type?

Comment: Same question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7166534/picturelistener-is-deprecated-and-obsolete-is-there-a-replacement/7877879#7877879

Comment: @ciscogambo Your reference to ActivityManager.restartPackage() makes your Aug 23 question less clear and focused than this one. It's strange that no one has been able to come with an answer since Aug 23. Perhaps the lack of a replacement is intentional? Security reasons?

Comment: Thanks @AndroidEve, I cleaned removed that from my question.

Comment: it has been 5 years but they haven't created alternative.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ok after careful review of the APIs, it seems this cannot be done without using PictureListener. Obviously the person who deprecated this feature didn't provide an alternative.

I suggest you write a bug report http://code.google.com/p/android/issues and ask people here to star it.

Emmanuel

Answer (score 5):

I submitted this Android issue to track the replacement for the PictureListener and onNewPicture() callback.

http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=38646

Please star as necessary.

Answer (score 1):

the closest thing you have is onPageFinished

```
wv.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
  @Override
  public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
    super.onPageFinished(view, url);

  }
});
```

but it doesn't always trigger after the content is finished being drawn, hence not so much of a replacement. I suggest sticking to onNewPicture even if it is deprecated. after all, it still works.

Answer (score 1):

Until there is an official replacement API for this functionality you can just change the

```
android:targetSdkVersion
```

in AndroidManifest.xml to anything <= 13.