# How to determine LAST WebViewClient.onPageFinished() call?

Tags: android, http, webview, android-webview

So, now that `PictureListener.onNewPicture()` is [deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7822481/picturelistener-and-onnewpicture-are-deprecated-alternatives), I must rely on some derivative of `WebViewClient.onPageFinished()`.

I can come up with some logic (with too many timers...) to do that, but one challenge remains: Some web pages deliver (for some strange reason) more than one `WebViewClient.onPageFinished()`.

I'm only interested in the **last one**.

Is there a way to tell whether another `WebViewClient.onPageFinished()` is **impending**?

(also, an explanation of what circumstances cause more than one `WebViewClient.onPageFinished()` to be triggered, for the same page request, would be most helpful to my understanding).